# Problem with SSPI/Kerberos authorization on windows service

Tags: service, authorization, kerberos, sspi

**Dear programmers!**

Today I have faced a serious problem, that I don't know how to approach.

I'm trying to implement an authorization service, using SSPI/Kerberos. I'm testing it on my local computer. When I implement server size as a windows service application, authorization process is cycling, i.e. function InitializeSecurityContext is always returning SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED. If I compile server as a usual windows application, cycling never happens and authorization process successfully completes. Both client and server use the same code. The difference in authorization process begins to appear whet server calls function AcquireCredentialsHandle. Service is executing under the current user account.

I'l try to illustrate this with concrete data:

**Case I. Both client and server are windows applications.**

1. Client: AcquireCredentialsHandle; 
   Returns: SEC_E_OK
2. Client: InitializeSecurityContext; 
   Returns: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED; 
   Token: (96, 61, 6, 10, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 18, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 48, 45, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 3, 2, 1, 16, 162, 20, 48, 18, 160, 3, 2, 1, 1, 161, 11, 48, 9, 27, 7, 69, 73, 115, 97, 121, 101, 118, 163, 11, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77)
3. Server: AcceptSecurityContext
   Returns: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
   Token: (96, 130, 4, 45, 6, 10, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 18, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 48, 130, 4, 27, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 3, 2, 1, 17, 162, 130, 4, 13, 97, 130, 4, 9, 48, 130, 4, 5, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 11, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77, 162, 30, 48, 28, 160, 3, 2, 1, 2, 161, 21, 48, 19, 27, 6, 107, 114, 98, 116, 103, 116, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77, 163, 130, 3, 207, 48, 130, 3, 203, 160, 3, 2, 1, 23, 161, 3, 2, 1, 2, 162, 130, 3, 189, 4, 130, 3, 185, 19, 169, 28, 176, 116, 14, 232, 162, 156, 233, 149, 48, 92, 255, 50, 12, 193, 3, 186, 15, 34, 188, 122, 124, 163, 106, 183, 17, 10, 169, 106, 102, 227, 11, 76, 92, 253, 71, 236, 84, 62, 86, 183, 49, 198, 5, 69, 8, 100, 10, 255, 106, 140, 168, 168, 119, 105, 244, 201, 170, 49, 21, 231, 3, 222, 144, 155, 234, 130, 119, 101, 163, 111, 116, 134, 251, 239, 130, 62, 98, 2, 0, 165, 221, 139, 93, 229, 128, 4, 134, 150, 215, 18, 64, 95, 25, 123, 245, 44, 111, 14, 97, 253, 227, 20, 113, 88, 255, 157, 92, 246, 170, 30, 8, 239, 80, 172, 153, 88, 236, 163, 112, 96, 115, 210, 238, 198, 126, 89, 161, 32, 59, 172, 233, 153, 48, 246, 185, 240, 97, 47, 114, 182, 117, 185, 58, 90, 122, 218, 165, 13, 105, 134, 76, 151, 243, 107, 170, 3, 35, 128, 207, 54, 95, 245, 112, 153, 208, 177, 122, 198, 32, 249, 17, 69, 17, 247, 187, 152, 44, 252, 19, 136, 49, 105, 116, 154, 24, 175, 167, 42, 5, 251, 193, 14, 133, 7, 68, 174, 85, 98, 221, 137, 246, 180, 234, 45, 21, 100, 197, 115, 209, 163, 28, 140, 76, 45, 227, 42, 190, 118, 169, 114, 135, 223, 151, 11, 204, 37, 178, 11, 174, 97, 168, 106, 39, 191, 29, 102, 64, 126, 57, 162, 123, 32, 69, 147, 168, 198, 24, 202, 196, 223, 90, 35, 163, 201, 11, 47, 23, 119, 217, 200, 75, 200, 27, 71, 147, 130, 218, 80, 58, 195, 206, 246, 188, 67, 242, 130, 46, 128, 57, 110, 51, 181, 43, 248, 36, 10, 96, 241, 181, 203, 98, 58, 158, 133, 197, 197, 196, 29, 28, 131, 183, 20, 42, 101, 86, 240, 179, 227, 94, 80, 97, 128, 60, 195, 42, 90, 141, 132, 102, 224, 114, 31, 190, 20, 40, 216, 38, 143, 214, 104, 48, 187, 251, 119, 52, 40, 26, 230, 50, 193, 134, 0, 38, 228, 166, 23, 192, 105, 224, 116, 11, 139, 155, 214, 6, 29, 152, 34, 73, 78, 67, 191, 109, 153, 108, 216, 176, 113, 158, 49, 245, 237, 9, 88, 255, 187, 18, 158, 18, 236, 83, 111, 111, 34, 181, 29, 46, 248, 184, 106, 29, 183, 134, 181, 38, 97, 13, 208, 242, 234, 186, 105, 112, 209, 229, 127, 200, 14, 138, 207, 150, 249, 95, 225, 85, 1, 230, 219, 168, 245, 90, 243, 194, 129, 49, 198, 165, 106, 45, 153, 149, 73, 0, 63, 60, 29, 169, 97, 243, 190, 47, 63, 137, 205, 108, 222, 89, 95, 252, 87, 108, 78, 195, 120, 242, 159, 64, 108, 84, 172, 6, 50, 123, 57, 148, 82, 87, 122, 190, 127, 124, 11, 41, 199, 14, 62, 102, 238, 173, 100, 218, 104, 209, 169, 44, 223, 59, 238, 77, 2, 58, 232, 229, 238, 157, 199, 217, 156, 1, 221, 11, 47, 175, 41, 16, 136, 227, 101, 227, 185, 82, 213, 195, 68, 194, 134, 33, 197, 251, 45, 14, 81, 9, 71, 174, 108, 71, 123, 41, 89, 111, 27, 107, 91, 117, 147, 49, 202, 242, 208, 191, 231, 21, 208, 30, 242, 120, 149, 252, 63, 11, 175, 52, 221, 99, 44, 97, 185, 117, 83, 213, 42, 75, 235, 85, 155, 101, 157, 29, 168, 94, 134, 26, 212, 212, 83, 77, 132, 232, 86, 124, 138, 211, 155, 136, 246, 44, 41, 111, 136, 208, 25, 176, 98, 27, 175, 116, 142, 207, 27, 8, 52, 63, 8, 203, 12, 140, 95, 93, 8, 143, 105, 191, 155, 49, 131, 59, 63, 140, 99, 186, 102, 59, 255, 242, 223, 207, 148, 252, 81, 77, 149, 166, 200, 26, 42, 66, 192, 201, 37, 36, 38, 110, 7, 210, 224, 220, 223, 233, 2, 231, 113, 91, 98, 73, 66, 242, 182, 85, 92, 240, 214, 173, 7, 78, 135, 10, 111, 145, 51, 124, 191, 49, 49, 84, 9, 241, 178, 47, 99, 147, 234, 210, 106, 156, 185, 203, 215, 111, 175, 202, 179, 59, 98, 115, 163, 60, 166, 29, 100, 100, 24, 102, 173, 210, 159, 253, 140, 136, 39, 142, 11, 229, 217, 142, 20, 23, 65, 150, 249, 253, 189, 150, 82, 109, 59, 217, 131, 27, 27, 63, 92, 43, 12, 93, 109, 146, 140, 60, 157, 81, 69, 152, 243, 151, 35, 203, 83, 200, 23, 175, 81, 15, 168, 81, 112, 32, 154, 227, 186, 82, 253, 110, 24, 17, 171, 201, 184, 207, 106, 92, 27, 165, 215, 156, 97, 90, 103, 77, 180, 230, 17, 213, 151, 216, 201, 58, 211, 217, 38, 95, 249, 33, 169, 161, 33, 236, 55, 18, 155, 166, 105, 94, 189, 233, 205, 0, 164, 147, 40, 178, 152, 201, 104, 56, 17, 118, 71, 161, 127, 99, 91, 107, 175, 169, 220, 38, 12, 88, 90, 213, 111, 249, 41, 7, 97, 175, 252, 44, 8, 191, 168, 140, 227, 6, 102, 44, 125, 23, 141, 226, 120, 174, 242, 40, 237, 174, 241, 83, 4, 250, 116, 112, 94, 2, 204, 54, 12, 163, 175, 68, 78, 155, 162, 241, 180, 123, 98, 137, 28, 17, 13, 22, 191, 224, 183, 227, 235, 17, 44, 184, 124, 189, 228, 7, 162, 16, 28, 116, 153, 72, 42, 55, 130, 164, 216, 70, 234, 86, 149, 240, 220, 47, 20, 190, 16, 151, 224, 80, 78, 228, 42, 137, 235, 230, 35, 72, 5, 167, 71, 165, 15, 201, 26, 141, 7, 125, 61, 110, 166, 248, 241, 187, 87, 248, 129, 79, 177, 123, 138)
4. Client: InitializeSecurityContext
   Returns: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
   Token: 96, 130, 5, 175, 6, 10, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 18, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0, 110, 130, 5, 157, 48, 130, 5, 153, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 3, 2, 1, 14, 162, 7, 3, 5, 0, 64, 0, 0, 0, 163, 130, 4, 198, 97, 130, 4, 194, 48, 130, 4, 190, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 11, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77, 162, 20, 48, 18, 160, 3, 2, 1, 1, 161, 11, 48, 9, 27, 7, 69, 73, 115, 97, 121, 101, 118, 163, 130, 4, 146, 48, 130, 4, 142, 160, 3, 2, 1, 23, 162, 130, 4, 133, 4, 130, 4, 129, 0, 122, 25, 198, 250, 165, 234, 139, 122, 22, 188, 165, 237, 202, 221, 56, 118, 26, 86, 203, 188, 231, 223, 53, 119, 189, 76, 73, 144, 19, 206, 154, 171, 33, 195, 180, 251, 46, 157, 163, 41, 48, 193, 47, 53, 247, 237, 202, 228, 170, 67, 166, 100, 70, 94, 18, 130, 115, 202, 44, 211, 80, 195, 108, 125, 214, 205, 188, 4, 68, 168, 200, 10, 16, 217, 250, 199, 249, 139, 208, 73, 63, 198, 28, 247, 105, 67, 239, 138, 243, 248, 73, 169, 29, 129, 192, 205, 120, 243, 171, 84, 95, 178, 111, 110, 233, 74, 53, 70, 125, 182, 35, 172, 228, 122, 205, 174, 10, 70, 242, 208, 63, 223, 172, 143, 132, 150, 29, 188, 38, 43, 92, 55, 253, 76, 252, 249, 78, 247, 6, 68, 0, 46, 151, 131, 16, 140, 30, 183, 98, 9, 13, 251, 7, 229, 146, 101, 108, 88, 217, 31, 107, 176, 214, 226, 177, 193, 235, 149, 33, 179, 1, 221, 157, 118, 234, 39, 241, 4, 177, 221, 131, 188, 222, 38, 209, 200, 52, 52, 33, 84, 168, 186, 212, 222, 200, 109, 126, 15, 113, 251, 202, 184, 140, 106, 18, 158, 109, 148, 83, 12, 225, 247, 224, 112, 112, 144, 112, 151, 204, 166, 249, 42, 75, 185, 32, 199, 247, 73, 121, 140, 143, 40, 214, 123, 65, 52, 138, 172, 151, 31, 126, 207, 196, 30, 44, 170, 32, 69, 180, 14, 172, 135, 56, 182, 195, 76, 171, 12, 61, 207, 119, 66, 213, 240, 204, 128, 21, 27, 245, 222, 80, 228, 202, 12, 63, 92, 49, 140, 96, 227, 107, 10, 8, 191, 14, 76, 8, 74, 164, 190, 110, 217, 192, 117, 255, 14, 77, 83, 156, 183, 249, 45, 3, 158, 223, 28, 108, 73, 41, 185, 40, 29, 227, 54, 44, 88, 179, 165, 173, 92, 55, 86, 235, 46, 126, 224, 86, 35, 21, 43, 25, 2, 62, 81, 159, 52, 173, 23, 179, 192, 229, 125, 235, 232, 113, 165, 47, 249, 130, 141, 176, 147, 106, 173, 75, 139, 119, 16, 24, 152, 116, 202, 11, 210, 108, 138, 222, 36, 215, 177, 254, 199, 235, 252, 18, 162, 169, 107, 33, 42, 177, 130, 154, 95, 187, 196, 111, 143, 63, 134, 207, 133, 16, 78, 246, 116, 36, 160, 184, 220, 183, 15, 64, 49, 205, 255, 106, 4, 226, 125, 213, 47, 197, 109, 202, 245, 51, 50, 254, 224, 39, 140, 86, 166, 97, 207, 177, 26, 178, 103, 192, 221, 92, 220, 3, 155, 202, 175, 25, 93, 100, 209, 182, 56, 131, 65, 239, 12, 3, 163, 26, 77, 97, 180, 244, 3, 168, 178, 140, 52, 193, 247, 25, 174, 154, 155, 199, 45, 79, 217, 144, 190, 40, 98, 184, 2, 255, 190, 63, 247, 254, 34, 173, 26, 239, 60, 19, 204, 51, 9, 107, 68, 114, 22, 185, 235, 198, 170, 115, 131, 74, 132, 136, 76, 112, 134, 209, 201, 62, 241, 83, 62, 247, 221, 54, 222, 34, 84, 79, 48, 67, 120, 10, 138, 140, 160, 44, 123, 45, 178, 198, 62, 66, 82, 0, 56, 60, 30, 112, 85, 235, 47, 208, 88, 201, 240, 143, 121, 223, 207, 225, 159, 41, 156, 211, 176, 227, 237, 229, 60, 176, 154, 150, 84, 222, 34, 36, 220, 67, 99, 24, 149, 190, 239, 81, 120, 120, 43, 97, 125, 58, 91, 111, 128, 144, 92, 72, 223, 42, 206, 26, 88, 156, 47, 109, 168, 81, 169, 238, 134, 91, 74, 13, 230, 131, 77, 184, 232, 131, 172, 228, 156, 190, 230, 205, 88, 210, 157, 82, 106, 179, 76, 55, 169, 91, 8, 195, 72, 86, 237, 229, 63, 190, 219, 235, 192, 197, 120, 18, 219, 202, 199, 93, 105, 120, 99, 209, 52, 239, 37, 107, 224, 188, 134, 249, 20, 145, 133, 242, 226, 58, 137, 0, 130, 176, 77, 89, 182, 202, 52, 137, 192, 199, 72, 189, 238, 33, 247, 91, 101, 59, 228, 210, 241, 242, 225, 18, 91, 167, 207, 122, 196, 241, 251, 116, 136, 87, 138, 51, 1, 44, 90, 253, 222, 74, 163, 44, 197, 118, 150, 79, 189, 80, 81, 114, 159, 62, 100, 138, 165, 160, 156, 238, 35, 232, 198, 14, 99, 131, 30, 190, 27, 195, 226, 200, 13, 33, 52, 163, 186, 33, 120, 188, 214, 41, 249, 18, 26, 143, 93, 73, 76, 44, 139, 154, 237, 193, 136, 169, 90, 134, 205, 183, 102, 60, 36, 192, 39, 115, 163, 14, 153, 187, 110, 197, 57, 243, 72, 16, 129, 9, 68, 125, 16, 224, 201, 160, 78, 224, 99, 68, 162, 253, 194, 3, 92, 151, 148, 196, 63, 194, 64, 135, 156, 88, 169, 77, 159, 218, 109, 56, 54, 138, 87, 145, 16, 145, 175, 100, 177, 150, 224, 18, 187, 56, 58, 255, 174, 247, 119, 242, 96, 174, 219, 168, 132, 103, 107, 152, 216, 191, 208, 129, 70, 150, 136, 168, 23, 30, 13, 112, 144, 68, 156, 97, 241, 85, 227, 240, 24, 61, 8, 120, 86, 40, 38, 71, 182, 177, 233, 208, 117, 148, 74, 2, 248, 243, 25, 45, 80, 59, 178, 241, 79, 210, 236, 84, 200, 25, 151, 163, 96, 159, 202, 120, 50, 80, 212, 34, 143, 15, 178, 121, 40, 59, 250, 73, 214, 212, 28, 81, 96, 252, 243, 96, 247, 26, 145, 64, 210, 48, 46, 243, 249, 9, 206, 10, 79, 190, 49, 72, 95, 61, 101, 47, 187, 204, 36, 145, 199, 15, 211, 154, 195, 230, 245, 130, 169, 60, 116, 193, 124, 31, 77, 66, 246, 244, 15, 79, 203, 149, 213, 44, 60, 134, 62, 94, 209, 208, 211, 135, 99, 162, 147, 81, 237, 96, 53, 106, 88, 202, 119, 61, 231, 65, 198, 116, 113, 175, 254, 166, 163, 175, 168, 42, 167, 125, 80, 252, 141, 64, 191, 202, 81, 126, 145, 2, 130, 67, 181, 129, 251, 245, 80, 248, 211, 86, 252, 117, 216, 19, 211, 18, 195, 225, 189, 134, 108, 198, 227, 12, 188, 34, 229, 200, 216, 229, 221, 70, 34, 62, 40, 97, 142, 226, 138, 8, 24, 232, 198, 101, 62, 124, 94, 54, 140, 26, 245, 247, 152, 183, 144, 127, 216, 33, 119, 107, 201, 137, 118, 208, 188, 122, 133, 106, 239, 98, 42, 22, 139, 224, 102, 17, 24, 135, 135, 242, 107, 170, 43, 222, 98, 226, 50, 65, 216, 113, 254, 151, 127, 110, 228, 59, 168, 11, 219, 125, 204, 100, 206, 40, 64, 97, 253, 69, 212, 50, 30, 199, 223, 133, 118, 66, 10, 158, 35, 20, 8, 244, 142, 120, 249, 96, 123, 68, 188, 112, 67, 169, 85, 171, 98, 108, 21, 2, 155, 1, 153, 84, 212, 233, 100, 164, 129, 185, 48, 129, 182, 160, 3, 2, 1, 23, 162, 129, 174, 4, 129, 171, 141, 249, 105, 233, 232, 184, 219, 79, 59, 58, 26, 86, 94, 118, 27, 136, 43, 14, 34, 144, 224, 45, 133, 120, 120, 122, 140, 143, 56, 114, 98, 197, 156, 67, 56, 130, 118, 101, 132, 129, 180, 77, 133, 184, 170, 194, 203, 197, 143, 179, 33, 224, 186, 6, 104, 39, 236, 116, 192, 105, 45, 219, 235, 150, 91, 209, 11, 51, 114, 23, 133, 38, 205, 19, 86, 134, 119, 120, 205, 169, 136, 41, 113, 159, 19, 181, 96, 219, 26, 121, 46, 54, 168, 136, 101, 222, 98, 115, 100, 223, 216, 46, 103, 94, 23, 80, 125, 52, 143, 59, 18, 110, 175, 101, 217, 73, 122, 171, 144, 43, 214, 36, 211, 65, 4, 131, 5, 179, 255, 35, 87, 199, 17, 55, 69, 69, 121, 19, 166, 197, 116, 19, 124, 77, 59, 55, 149, 37, 246, 35, 82, 87, 47, 139, 164, 12, 212, 200, 254, 191, 6, 219, 134, 39, 84, 167, 114, 195, 84, 34, 115)
5. Server: AcceptSecurityContext
   Returns: SEC_E_OK
   Token: null

**Case II. Server is executing as a windows service.**

1. Client: AcquireCredentialsHandle; 
   Returns: SEC_E_OK
2. Client: InitializeSecurityContext; 
   Returns: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED; 
   Token: (96, 61, 6, 10, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 18, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 48, 45, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 3, 2, 1, 16, 162, 20, 48, 18, 160, 3, 2, 1, 1, 161, 11, 48, 9, 27, 7, 69, 73, 115, 97, 121, 101, 118, 163, 11, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77)
3. Server: AcceptSecurityContext
   Returns: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
   Token: (96, 130, 4, 45, 6, 10, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 18, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 48, 130, 4, 27, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 3, 2, 1, 17, 162, 130, 4, 13, 97, 130, 4, 9, 48, 130, 4, 5, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 11, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77, 162, 30, 48, 28, 160, 3, 2, 1, 2, 161, 21, 48, 19, 27, 6, 107, 114, 98, 116, 103, 116, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77, 163, 130, 3, 207, 48, 130, 3, 203, 160, 3, 2, 1, 23, 161, 3, 2, 1, 2, 162, 130, 3, 189, 4, 130, 3, 185, 75, 77, 243, 239, 123, 170, 48, 160, 60, 229, 219, 69, 209, 92, 48, 15, 126, 150, 200, 238, 73, 113, 192, 141, 253, 115, 242, 195, 208, 110, 48, 136, 183, 180, 189, 5, 118, 172, 143, 98, 88, 231, 192, 74, 124, 193, 119, 198, 248, 51, 23, 72, 255, 122, 147, 28, 140, 123, 119, 231, 221, 201, 55, 97, 246, 63, 224, 140, 103, 241, 121, 146, 97, 216, 124, 153, 92, 186, 10, 200, 19, 152, 226, 179, 133, 8, 102, 9, 95, 47, 41, 2, 119, 96, 141, 216, 220, 157, 177, 4, 251, 176, 114, 106, 246, 33, 143, 165, 168, 43, 192, 52, 148, 53, 110, 173, 99, 83, 212, 224, 3, 45, 117, 252, 95, 177, 112, 18, 14, 105, 77, 181, 71, 104, 157, 203, 44, 144, 31, 2, 132, 225, 133, 175, 255, 103, 245, 49, 51, 79, 116, 130, 68, 118, 136, 138, 0, 42, 238, 235, 168, 228, 174, 240, 111, 7, 209, 119, 205, 141, 193, 26, 97, 203, 148, 73, 31, 39, 118, 202, 218, 67, 78, 128, 120, 108, 123, 229, 72, 217, 26, 251, 20, 97, 38, 207, 196, 208, 235, 100, 117, 89, 13, 97, 170, 184, 197, 95, 24, 113, 178, 30, 177, 131, 36, 87, 220, 241, 229, 153, 196, 253, 111, 92, 55, 138, 90, 168, 36, 219, 78, 149, 41, 19, 130, 114, 147, 50, 99, 227, 253, 95, 31, 208, 13, 66, 175, 169, 21, 70, 128, 175, 172, 234, 161, 249, 31, 249, 95, 13, 154, 15, 253, 119, 187, 198, 222, 72, 131, 241, 68, 23, 12, 234, 199, 80, 23, 235, 172, 184, 42, 250, 74, 110, 235, 136, 44, 163, 77, 204, 196, 114, 145, 26, 141, 133, 147, 206, 178, 69, 38, 98, 185, 106, 151, 68, 47, 93, 48, 201, 4, 191, 45, 122, 146, 102, 182, 180, 93, 39, 72, 243, 105, 16, 240, 245, 143, 66, 235, 214, 146, 172, 221, 108, 26, 112, 219, 244, 40, 147, 181, 72, 214, 83, 207, 223, 5, 134, 202, 114, 97, 192, 175, 87, 187, 59, 97, 91, 135, 153, 85, 37, 193, 20, 104, 98, 140, 162, 254, 133, 159, 246, 41, 78, 197, 141, 218, 119, 108, 71, 140, 162, 190, 130, 236, 44, 235, 135, 175, 66, 82, 109, 180, 30, 127, 33, 102, 62, 154, 224, 175, 208, 200, 174, 241, 9, 183, 85, 198, 61, 164, 203, 9, 204, 231, 21, 162, 225, 80, 219, 211, 203, 146, 27, 6, 77, 199, 177, 240, 229, 170, 222, 16, 153, 37, 238, 127, 226, 175, 175, 229, 43, 94, 127, 160, 205, 101, 195, 82, 144, 206, 148, 187, 103, 125, 172, 47, 4, 182, 235, 167, 236, 107, 188, 198, 219, 57, 224, 80, 116, 58, 231, 214, 178, 235, 199, 75, 66, 128, 107, 163, 197, 22, 216, 65, 98, 131, 0, 183, 236, 135, 0, 85, 62, 123, 154, 146, 91, 111, 70, 49, 181, 163, 178, 217, 63, 191, 57, 13, 169, 120, 45, 173, 135, 124, 30, 103, 90, 45, 178, 183, 156, 225, 209, 123, 73, 25, 182, 204, 252, 5, 114, 186, 97, 17, 35, 128, 174, 19, 30, 20, 76, 106, 185, 62, 1, 250, 223, 225, 213, 101, 23, 20, 48, 71, 62, 208, 175, 1, 79, 121, 19, 187, 209, 120, 219, 45, 201, 57, 5, 182, 243, 99, 41, 223, 128, 49, 77, 146, 215, 42, 167, 228, 18, 15, 231, 229, 249, 135, 252, 183, 223, 166, 172, 103, 181, 20, 67, 185, 178, 5, 215, 214, 46, 237, 161, 251, 127, 20, 0, 140, 207, 202, 198, 107, 186, 126, 131, 148, 131, 174, 94, 121, 237, 94, 214, 122, 173, 135, 164, 7, 98, 143, 131, 32, 14, 34, 209, 152, 108, 134, 6, 77, 94, 50, 224, 193, 182, 71, 44, 169, 32, 57, 11, 40, 222, 177, 108, 134, 133, 117, 163, 194, 225, 204, 210, 166, 176, 112, 205, 140, 16, 114, 39, 107, 148, 240, 40, 39, 26, 75, 137, 118, 88, 62, 69, 31, 192, 178, 185, 88, 123, 57, 234, 16, 23, 82, 105, 83, 88, 155, 10, 226, 224, 131, 167, 145, 61, 151, 39, 217, 221, 208, 90, 191, 30, 73, 37, 122, 43, 26, 176, 93, 120, 63, 136, 147, 123, 63, 175, 103, 11, 75, 30, 7, 27, 205, 226, 168, 191, 224, 239, 143, 204, 186, 83, 200, 152, 61, 237, 131, 58, 240, 137, 81, 156, 130, 161, 254, 102, 98, 168, 221, 155, 53, 110, 131, 162, 137, 64, 19, 38, 50, 243, 62, 185, 126, 11, 189, 212, 124, 61, 106, 109, 15, 73, 226, 160, 255, 86, 215, 66, 112, 174, 195, 123, 99, 222, 18, 111, 244, 49, 1, 120, 115, 209, 65, 208, 195, 243, 76, 158, 210, 1, 202, 168, 5, 235, 26, 52, 252, 72, 65, 242, 168, 59, 55, 81, 227, 161, 224, 88, 139, 55, 189, 165, 117, 120, 240, 245, 221, 119, 152, 78, 81, 232, 136, 172, 130, 20, 57, 147, 80, 140, 85, 38, 128, 0, 233, 168, 254, 52, 221, 0, 63, 244, 119, 140, 136, 197, 62, 109, 73, 241, 238, 7, 194, 221, 227, 227, 175, 13, 128, 207, 1, 49, 98, 214, 220, 47, 85, 132, 16, 9, 147, 222, 119, 151, 175, 29, 66, 194, 226, 84, 94, 251, 3, 253, 211, 89, 198, 115, 225, 237, 56, 221, 51, 154, 47, 9, 55, 120, 56, 128, 5, 92, 92, 9, 193, 111, 75, 121, 32, 77, 212, 133, 23, 191, 94, 87, 255, 80, 99, 39, 128, 171, 98, 25, 22, 27, 150, 192, 50)
4. Client: InitializeSecurityContext
   Returns: SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED
   Token: (96, 61, 6, 10, 42, 134, 72, 134, 247, 18, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 0, 48, 45, 160, 3, 2, 1, 5, 161, 3, 2, 1, 16, 162, 20, 48, 18, 160, 3, 2, 1, 1, 161, 11, 48, 9, 27, 7, 69, 73, 115, 97, 121, 101, 118, 163, 11, 27, 9, 86, 73, 84, 80, 67, 46, 67, 79, 77)

And from here items 3 and 4 cycle.

Comment: Remove the bytes, they are useless here and make the question unreadable.